# wordpress orderby with two post types

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two post types
post
product

In main query I want list both, but with some conditional.

- post - orderby menu_order ASC + post_date DESC
- product - orderby random

It would be great something similiar

1. "post"
2. "product"
3. "post"
4. "product"
5. "post"
6. "product" etc...

or better it would be random

1. "product"
2. "post"
3. "post"
4. "product"
5. "post"
6. "product"
7. "post"
8. "post"
9. "product"

It is possible via mysql orderby?
Thank you so much

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You want randomly place "products" between sorted "posts"?

Comment: yes, exactly. it is possible?

Comment: I think it's possible, but wouldn't do it SQL.